Orthogonal complement with respect to a subspace, and then with respect to the larger space.
Suppose I have the subspaces $W\leq V \leq \mathbb{F}_q^n$, with $n$ finite. Let $\langle ,\rangle\colon\mathbb{F}_q^n\times \mathbb{F}_q^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q$ be the dot-product. If I then take the orthogonal complement (I know this is not necessarily a complement) of $W$ inside $V$, that is
$W^{\perp V}=\{v\in V | \forall w\in W:\langle v,w\rangle =0\}$, and then take $(W^{\perp V})^{\perp}=\{x\in \mathbb{F}_q^n| \forall y\in W^{\perp V}:\langle x,y\rangle =0\}$. Does the latter then have a nice expression?

I can mistaken, but I don't think that there is a scalar product on such space... Indeed, a scalar product always induce a norm, but it's well known that $\mathbb F_q^n$'s spaces are not normed.

Updated the question as I meant the orthogonal complement (not necessarily a complement of course) under the dot-product.

As I said, there is no dot product in such spaces...

Certainly you can call the pairing
$$\langle(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$$
a dot product. After all, what else would you mean by a dot product here :-)
Anyway, this is not an inner product in the usual sense familiar from real/complex vector spaces. In order not to fight about terminology we could agree to call it a non-degenerate bilinear form. Basically meaning that the dot product is linear w.r.t. both variables, and that there is no vector orthogonal to everything else. Such beasts are well studied objects in algebra.

But, I don't know how much can be said about the actual question in general. The case $q=2$ is particularly well studied in [tag:coding-theory]. Anyway, it is possible that $V\subseteq V^\perp$, when the restriction of the dot product to $V$ vanishes identically. A simple example of this is with $q=2$, $n=4$ and $V$ spanned by the vectors $1100$ and $0011$, both orthogonal to each other as well as themselves. A more interesting example is the so called extended Hamming code of length 8, spanned by $11111111, 00001111, 00110011, 01010101$. An even more interesting case is the binary Golay code.

(cont'd) My point is that when $V\subseteq V^\perp$ you have $W^{\perp B}=V$ irrespective of the choice of $W$! This is a bit un-natural, and raises the question of what you would call a nice expression. Not saying that there would bo universal description! May be $W^{\perp V}=W^\perp\cap V$ is a useful starting point. Is there a nice description of $(V_1\cap V_2)^\perp$? It's 6 a.m. here and I haven't had enough coffee.

Rats. Should read $W^{\perp V}=V$ in the previous comment.
